# How to get ranked values of a pandas column without gaps?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, rank

In this way

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col':['bbb','aaa','aaa','ccc']})
print df
print '-------------'
df['ranked'] = df['col'].rank(method='min')
print df
```

I get:

```
   col
0  bbb
1  aaa
2  aaa
3  ccc
-------------
   col  ranked
0  bbb       3
1  aaa       1
2  aaa       1
3  ccc       4
```

And I would like to have:

```
   col
0  bbb
1  aaa
2  aaa
3  ccc
-------------
   col  ranked
0  bbb       2
1  aaa       1
2  aaa       1
3  ccc       3
```

Does anybody know how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col':['bbb','aaa','aaa','ccc']})
print df
print '-------------'

df2 = df.drop_duplicates()
df2['ranked'] = df2.rank(method='min')
print df.merge(df2, on='col')
```

Output:

```
   col
0  bbb
1  aaa
2  aaa
3  ccc
-------------
   col  ranked
0  bbb       2
1  aaa       1
2  aaa       1
3  ccc       3
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work for `df = pandas.DataFrame({'col':['bbb','aaa','ccc','aaa']})`.

Comment: @Roman, Ohh!, yes you have a point, I've updated my answer with another approach, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Series.rank(method="dense")`, which is like min but just doesn't skip numbers:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html